# How to just return the 67th digit of square root of 2 using only two built-in functions in maple

Tags: maple

I tried using floor function and mod function, however this did not work.I tried using 'a' as variable with the expression: sqrt(2)* 10^65, then variable 'b' as: floor(a).After that i used the expression floor((b-a)*10).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether construction of the representation of sqrt(2) (eg. `sqrt(2)` or `2^(1/2)`) counts as one of the built-in functions.

Also, do arithmetic operations count? If not then the following uses only `trunc` and `frac`.

```
trunc(10*frac(sqrt(2)*10^65));

      0
```

Also, does the syntex for indexing count as one of the built-in functions?

If not, then the following uses just `String` and `evalf`,

```
String(evalf[68](2^(1/2)))[-2];

      "0"
```

We do a visual check,

```
evalf[70](sqrt(2));
```

1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732

Comment: In case it's not clear, compare with the result from `seq( trunc(10*frac(sqrt(2)*10^(p-2))), p=61..67)`